# Is it possible to put a part of PHP code in <script>?

Tags: php

I have a php page, within is an alert like so:

```
<script>
alert('Stop the timer!');
</script>";
```

now i'd like to try/do this:

```
<script>
<?php echo "$test2"; ?>
alert('Stop the timer!');
</script>
```

(what i try to do is to give back the content of $test2 by means of the alert...)

Now this does not work. but.... it doesn't give an error message either.

so 2 questions here are:

1) is it even possible to put a part of php in the  section
2) if it doesn't work why doesn't it give an error message
(3) do i have to make the $test2 global? (and how to best format it if so)

thanks in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <!-- deze hieronder is nodig voor touchpad enabled sliders -->
      <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">




        <script>
    function getSelectValues(select) {
      var result = [];
      var options = select && select.options;
      var opt;

      for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        opt = options[i];

        if (opt.selected) {
          result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
        </script>

      <!-- accordion -->
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
            event: "click",
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false

        });
      });
      </script>

      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
          orientation: "horizontal",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          value: 1,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
          }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
      });
      </script>
       <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#slider-vertical2" ).slider({
          orientation: "horizontal",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          value: 1,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.value );
          }
        });
        $( "#amount2" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical2" ).slider( "value" ) );
      });
      </script>
        <title>Left X Right -BrainGame</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
       <script>
      $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2(); </script>

     <style type="text/css">
    p.label_checkbox_pair {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    }
    p.label_checkbox_pair input {
    left: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    }
    p.label_checkbox_pair label {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script>
    <script>
    //oud $(document).ready(function(){
      //$('input').iCheck({
        //checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
        //radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
     // 


        //increaseArea: '20%'  optional
      //});
    //});
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
          label = self.next(),
          label_text = label.text();

        label.remove();
        self.iCheck({
          checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_line-blue',
          radioClass: 'iradio_line-blue',
          insert: '<div class="icheck_line-icon"></div>' + label_text
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
        <link href="skins/line/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">


        </head>

    <BODY>
    <br /><br />
    <table HSPACE="50" CELLPADDING="20">
    <tr HSPACE=50 CELLPADDING="30">
    <td>
    <?php 
    $a=array("red","blue","black","orange","green");
    $random_keys=array_rand($a,5);


    $textcolours=array('red','blue','black','orange','green');
    shuffle($textcolours);

    echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[0]' >".$a[$random_keys[0]]."<br><br></font></right>";
    echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[1]' >".$a[$random_keys[1]]."<br><br></font></right>";
    echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[2]' >".$a[$random_keys[2]]."<br><br></font></right>";
    echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[3]' >".$a[$random_keys[3]]."<br><br></font></rightr>";
    echo "<right><font size=6 color='$textcolours[4]' >".$a[$random_keys[4]]."<br><br></font></right>";
    ?>
    </td>

    <td>

      <div class="left">

         <form class="span4" action="" method="post">

      <fieldset>

        <legend>Left X Right  BrainGame</legend>

        <p halign="right" margin="10px">Name: <input type="text" name="naam" ></p>

        <p halign="right" margin="10px">Date: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" ></p>

     <br>

             <?php
    if(isset($_POST['getdata'])){
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost','t','w');
    mysql_select_db("test",$conn);

    $regexp = "/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/";

    $naam=$_POST['naam'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    //$type=$_POST['type'];
    //$core=$_POST['core'];
    //$management=$_POST['management'];


    //$names = $tools; 
    //$output = preg_grep('/(Andrew|John)/i', $names); 
    //print_r( $output );

    //
    //http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#match
    $test = $_POST['tools'];
    $result = preg_replace('/({|:|true|}|")/', '', $test);
    $test2 = preg_grep('/(^RED|^BLACK|^BLUE|^ORANGE|^GREEN|^red|^black|^blue|^orange|^green)/i', $result);

    $tools = json_encode($test2);
    //$tools = $_POST['tools'];
    //$tools = json_encode(preg_grep('/(RED|BLACK|BLUE|ORANGE|GREEN)/i', $_POST['tools']));
    //$tools = json_encode($_POST['tools']);
    //$analytisch=$_POST['analytisch'];
    //$eneagram=$_POST['eneagram'];

    if(true == false ){
        echo "<label class='err'>All fields are required</label>";
        }

            else{
    $insert="Insert into kandidaat(naam,date,tools)
     values('".$naam."','".$date."','".$tools."')";

    $rs=mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

    ?>
    <script>
    <?php echo "$test2"; ?>
    alert('Stop the timer!');

    </script>";
    <?php }
    }
     ?>

      </fieldset>


    <div id="accordion" style="width:90%;">
      <h3>Start...</h3>
      <div>
        <p class="label_checkbox_pair">

    <!--<div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="iCheck" value="true"><label for="certs">ISTQB2</label></div>-->
    <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[RED]" value="true"><label>RED</label></div>
    <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[BLUE]" value="true"><label>BLUE</label></div>
    <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[BLACK]" value="true"><label>BLACK</label></div>
    <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[ORANGE]" value="true"><label>ORANGE</label></div>
    <div style="font-family: arial; font-size: 6px; color: #0B1DE0; vertical-align: middle;"><input style="vertical-align: middle" type="checkbox" name="certs[GREEN]" value="true"><label>GREEN</label></div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <h3>Part 2</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        <!-- zie content website https://select2.github.io/examples.html -->
        <fieldset>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[RED]" value="true"><label>RED</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLUE]" value="true"><label>BLUE</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[BLACK]" value="true"><label>BLACK</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[ORANGE]" value="true"><label>ORANGE</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="tools[GREEN]" value="true"><label>GREEN</label></div>
    </fieldset>
    </p>
        </div>

    </div>


    <br/>    <button type="submit" name="getdata" class="btn">Submit</button>
    <a href="toonkandidaat.php" class="btn btn-primary">Highscores</a>


    </form>

       </div>
       <?php 
       function save(){

        }
       ?>
    <?php
    function make_links_clickable($text){
        return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z&#1072;-&#1103;&#1040;-&#1071;()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
    }
    ?>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Why dont you go and try it yourself?

Comment: like i said. i see nothing happening...and I'd like to know from fact if it could work before trying to see something that couldn't possibly be there :)

Comment: It should work. If you don't find the value of `$test2` in your script part on the client side, that means that `$test2` value is empty. Anyway, this won't alert the value of `$test2`, as you just print it in the script part and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax in wrong. Imagine your have saved foobar in your varibale.
If you print it like you the the result will be
    foobar

But your printed it inside the script part so you need to assign it to a JavaScript variable. There are two possibilities to alert it.

```
alert("<?php echo $test; ?>");
```

Or

```
var content = "<?php echo $test; ?>";
alert(content);
```

Comment: it gave back    Array.... so I tried .. alert("<?php echo json_encode($test2); ?>");              it gives back the same result as in the html table... namely   []

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
<script>
alert('<?php echo $test2; ?>');
</script>
```

The

```
alert('<?php echo $test2; ?>');
```

will be replaced by the content of your PHP variable ("Hello word" by example), just like you wrote this :

```
alert('Hello word');
```

Comment: Hey Simon, ben je Nederlander? I'm new in PHP so sorry for my lots of mistakes yet. the alert is now... :  Array           by the way i added the code especially for you. and by the way2... it is becomming a little brain game. als je het leuk vind om te helpen zou ik dat wel gaaf vinden misschien.... dan kan ik je laten zien wat ik tot nu toe heb.

Comment: Re, haha no I'm not dutch speaking :) I'm from Belgium, french side, but like a lot of Belgians I have a dutch name... :)

Maybe the content of your Php variable is not a string but an array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible due to the fact that PHP scripts are evaluated by a PHP interpreter on the Server first, before delivering plain HTML/CSS/JS to the client browser.

Anyways, it would have been faster to just go ahead and try it yourself.

For answering why it doesnt work in your case, we need more code to see how and where your variable(s) are defined.

Comment: is something like this possible?  $tools = json_encode(preg_grep('/(RED|BLACK|BLUE|ORANGE|GREEN)/i', $_POST['tools']));     ___if so, how to format it correctly?